# How to join opponent in room

Tags: node.js, join, socket.io

When X user try to create room with Y user. 
I do this:

```
socket.join(room.roomId);
UserConnectionId.findOne({userId: data.opponentId}).then((connection) => {
    //connection.connectionId is user's socket Id
    var socketList = io.sockets.server.eio.clients;
    if (socketList[connection.connectionId] != undefined){                    
        socketList[connection.connectionId].join(room.roomId);
    }
});
```

but show this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: socketList[connection.connectionId].join is not a function

How can I get socket object by socketId, and how to join this connection in room?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to handle error properly, I dont know what **socketList[connection.connectionId].join(room.roomId)** function do. Try this snipet to handle errors properly. Then check using manual of  **socketList[connection.connectionId].join(room.roomId)**  function

```
socket.join(room.roomId);
UserConnectionId.findOne({userId: data.opponentId})
.then((connection) => {
    //connection.connectionId is user's socket Id
    var socketList = io.sockets.server.eio.clients;
    if (socketList[connection.connectionId] != undefined){                    
        return socketList[connection.connectionId].join(room.roomId);
    }
});
.catch((errors) => {
    console.log(errors)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution*

I have changed 
`var socketList = io.sockets.server.eio.clients;`
with
`var socketList = io.sockets.sockets;`
it's fixed